# pip library body_measurements (python)

Tags: python, django, measurement

I want to get the body measurements through an image using pip library body_measurements.
Is there any material related to this? I have seen openCV2 library for this thing but that does not my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the [3D Body Measurements repository](https://github.com/vcarlosrb/3d-body-measurements), this is a library to get measures from an existing 3D mesh of a human body.
Therefore you first would need to find a way to obtain such a 3D mesh of a person from an image in order to use the body_measurements module.

The library seems to be intended to work with [SMPL](https://smpl.is.tue.mpg.de/) models, which is a whole framework for learning and inferring human poses etc. from  images.
However it is a little unclear what your requirements are.